# For print a pattern by using loop

Tags: c++, loops

**this is my output*

```
1234
 234
  34
   4
```

**code**
//variable declaration

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
    int i,j,space,star,n;
    cin>>n;
    i=1;
```

//for printing spaces

```
while(i<=n){
 space=i-1;
  while(space){
     cout<<" ";
     space--;
  }
```

// for counting variables

```
 j=1;
    star=n-i+1;
```

// for printing numbers

```
while(star){        
    int num=i+j-1;        
    cout<<num;       
    star--;
    j++;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
       i++;
    }
    return 0;
    
    }
```

**Que**- I want that as an output :-

```
1 2 3 4
  2 3 4
    3 4
      4
```

Comment: I appreciate that you provided your code with your actual and expected results, yet it would be far more convenient if you could edit your question to put all your code in one block instead of several snippets.

Comment: Please turn that puzzle into a [mre].

Comment: So you want a blank after each character you currently output? What keeps you from just outputting one after each character?

Comment: yes, I want a blank after every number.

Comment: No, trust me, You want more than that. But let's start there. What keeps from outputting a blank after each time you output a number?

Comment: space variable count spaces.

Comment: That does not seem to be an answer to my question "What keeps you from outputting blanks where you want them?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when printing spaces, you do this:

```
 cout<<" ";
```

You can do this:

```
 cout<<"  ";
```

That is, print two spaces instead of one. That's half your answer.

Later you do this:

```
cout<<num;
```

You can do this:

```
cout << num << " ";
```

That is -- print the digit plus a space.

Done. However, if you do that, then you get an extra trailing space at the end of the line, So you can do this.

```
std::string delim = "";
while (star) {        
    int num=i+j-1;        
    cout << delim << num;
    delim = " ";     
    star--;
    j++;
}
```

This is your code with very very simple changes. I added a variable delim and changed the cout statement slight.

The first time through the loop, `delim` is an empty string, so adding it to the `cout` statement does nothing. After that, `delim` is a single space, so now you print a space before all but the very first digit.

On a side note -- please make more use of whitespace. Cramming everything together becomes very hard to read for those of us getting older, and it's a common way to obscure bugs. That's a style thing, but it WILL save you HOURS of time in the future.